# Manually assigning mirror pairs?

Tags: bones, mirror

Is it possible to set bones as the X-axis mirror of each other other than with the .L and .R suffixes?

For example, is there some option where I could manually convince Blender that "Left_Thigh" and "Right_Thigh" are a pair (and thus mirror any edits on one to the other)?

I have to export to an engine that doesn't like periods/full-stops in bone names, and I'd really rather not have to keep swapping the names back-and-forth every time I export for testing.

Any answer is appreciated, even if it's "No". (At least it'll save me time barking up the wrong tree).

Comment: It also works with L. and R. prefixes and Left. and Right. prefixes work too and also Left_ and Right_ prefixes too :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes bones are mirrored if you enable *x-axis mirror* and as long as everything in the name is the same except 'Left' and 'Right' and can even be directly next to a letter if you use it as *suffix*. If you use 'Left' and 'Right' as *prefix*, then separate with '.' (period) or '_' (underscore)

But if you use 'L' and 'R' it cannot be next to a letter, but has to be separated with '.' (period) or '_' (underscore)

For example prefixes:

- L.Bone and R.Bone
- Left.Bone and Right.Bone
- L_Bone and R_Bone
- Left_Bone and Right_Bone

or suffixes:

- Bone.L and Bone.R
- Bone.Left and Bone.Right
- Bone_L and Bone_R
- Bone_Left and Bone_Right
- BoneLeft and BoneRight

[image]

Comment: Ah - maybe that's why it's not working. 

I somewhat oversimplified my example - I'm currently rigging a spider daemon (which means some fairly complex bone naming, particularly as I want things to alphabetise in a certain order), and I'd previously been told that the regexes were able to work in the *middle* of a bone name.

I'll get back to you on that one.